# Take Screenshot of Android screen and save to SD card

Tags: java, android, screenshot, sd-card

There are a few questions here on SO about capturing screenshots of an android application. However, I haven't found a solid solution on how to take a screenshot programatically using the android SDK or any other method.

So I thought I would ask this question again in the hopes that I can find a good solution, hopefully one that will allow capturing full length images that I can save to the SD card or somewhere similar.

I appreicate any help

Comment: We had a similar question but I found an answer.  Here's a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939987/android-take-screenshot-via-code

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible directly on the device/emulator, unless it is rooted.

> to honest all I need it for is the emulator as this is for a testing application on a PC

This sounds like a job for [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there is a reason why Android can't do this? Is it a policy decision by the Android developers or is it a limitation somewhere in Android itself?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: It is a policy decision to not have an API for it, AFAIK. Why they don't have their own OS-supplied app for screenshots, I can't say.

Comment: Thanks. Not that I personally have a use for it - I just find it curious that it isn't a standard feature.

Comment: As the MonkeyRunner doc explains, it's easy to assume that MonkeyRunner is just a runner for the Monkey tool, in which case one (aka, I) might skip the MonkeyRunner doc altogether. I suggest adding "NOT related to Monkey" to the entry in the tools TOC.

Answer (score 1):

monkeyrunner tool can do the job for you with bit of adb command, [python script]

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
//waits for connection
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
//take the current snapshot
device.takeSnapshot()
//stores the current snapshot in current dir in pc
device.writeToFile('current.png')\
//copy it to the sd card of device
os.subprocess.call('adb push current.png /sdcard/android/com.test.myapp/current.png')
```

Note: call this jython script file
    monkeyrunner.bat   <file name>

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely not be happy with this answer, but the only ones that I have seen involve using native code, or executing native commands.

Edit: 
I hadn't seen this one before. Have you tried it?:
http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/

Edit2: Checked that library, and it also is a bad solution. Requires that you start the service from a pc. So my initial answer still holds :)

Edit3: You should be able to save a view as an image by doing something similar to this. You might need to tweek it a bit so that you get the width/height of the view. (I'm inflating layouts, and specify the width/height when I layout the code)

```
View content = getView();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
File file = new File(pathAndFilename);              
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
ostream.close();
```

Comment: to honest all I need it for is the emulator as this is for a testing application on a PC. I have had a look at that library before and I couldn't find a way to turn it from a background service to a class. If I use it as a service it requires that I need to start it every time after a reboot, which is not ideal for me.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a view that you have created, and you want to take a screenshot of that view? That is not that hard.

Comment: that is exactly what I am saying. It would be great if I could get the full length of the view too (its scrollable) but that might not be possible.

Comment: See my edited answer. I posted some code that you should be able to use.

Comment: if just from the emulator, why not just use the screenshot button in eclipse (Devices Perspective)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at http://codaset.com/jens-riboe/droidatscreen/wiki (with a write up at http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/droidscreen/): this is a Java library that uses `adb` to capture a screen shots. I've been able to (with a lot of elbow grease) modify the source to let me automatically capture a timed series of screen shots (which I use for demo videos).

You can see the class structure at http://pastebin.com/hX5rQsSR

EDIT: You'd invoke it (after bundling all the requirements) like this:

java -cp DroidScreen.jar --adb "" --device "" --prefix "" --interval