# Android take screenshot via code

Tags: android, sms, screenshot

This shouldn't be too tough of a question.  I want the ability to take a screenshot of my layout (view) and send it via sms.  Can someone walk me though the steps?

Thanks!

Edit:
It doesn't have to be a 'screenshot' I guess, just as long as we can get all of the rendered pixels from a view somehow.

Comment: You need run the search before asking the question. Here's almost exact dupe http://goo.gl/K9ezs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take Screenshot of Android screen and save to SD card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929403/take-screenshot-of-android-screen-and-save-to-sd-card)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Around the web I found some snippets of code that I was able to get working together.

Here is a solution that works well:

Setting up your Root layout:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutroot);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Function to get the rendered view:

```
private void getScreen()
{
    View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutroot);
    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    File file = new File("/sdcard/test.png");
    try 
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your AndroidManifest and instead of hardcoding `/sdcard/` use `File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.png");`

Comment: @Peanut i used this solution. test.png is created in sdcard. but actully  the image is not created  it shows 0kb. and i get the null pointer exception here "  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);"

Comment: Got the solution here thanks.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null