# To save image from imageView in android

Tags: android, eclipse, image

I have an image in  image-view and i want to save image from image-view to gallery or any storage space can anyone tell me how to do this??? 
Thank you.

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you get the bitmap rom the drawing cache:

```
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
```

There are several questions here with answers showing full code:

- [Android take screenshot via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939987/android-take-screenshot-via-code)
- [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android)

These are methods of the View class, so they are applicable to any derived one (including ImageView)

Comment: +1: I wanted to extract the image from imageview. Works perfect for me !!! Thnx @Aleadam.

Answer (score 0):

You could hold a Bitmap Object in Background this piece of code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0,
    originalBitmap.width(), originalBitmap.height(), matrix, true);
```

And save it later using this code:

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(strDirectoy,imgname);
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```