# Snapshot of imageview which have image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using imageview with rotating and zooming the image in imageview by two fingers. when i zoom the image its zooming i want part of image which is seen on imageview currently after zooming
How can i do this please help me for this is it possible to take snapshot of that imageview of that time instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following, where `v1` is your ImageView, and the body here would be called from some 'capture' button.

```
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
```

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160077/420001).