# Android: saving all the contents of a xml layout (imageviews, etc) as an image file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sdcard

I am creating an application that basically places a drawable into an imageView onClick.  The result is a screen with a bunch of images on it in certain places.  I want to save this screen as an image on the SD Card on the user's phone.  I already know how to convert one imageView to a bitmap and save it to the SD Card, but how can I save all of the imageViews the way they are laid out on the screen as one file?

I have searched for an answer to this for several days.  I was first thinking of programming in a button that would take a screenshot, but everything that I am reading says that you can only use screenshot on rooted phones.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png

Comment: You can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939987/android-take-screenshot-via-code . Also, please read the comments on the selected answer.

Comment: thank you so much worked great!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap = findViewById(your_layout_id).getDrawingCache();
File file = new File(path_to_store_file);
if(!file.exists())    
    file.createNewFile();
try{
   FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, (OutputStream)ostream);
 } 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```